# Unit test case for anonymously defining interface

Tags: unit-testing, junit4, powermock, easymock

I have an interface for implementing callback:-

```
public interface Callback {
    void printData(String data);
}
```

My class for which I want to write unit test case

```
public class MainClass{
    public void getData(String data)
    {
      // here I am calling another class which accepts that interface as param and implementing it anonymously

       otherClass.getOtherData(data, new new Callback() {
            void printData(String data)
            {
              // do some logic with data
            }
       });
    }
}
```

When I am writing the test case for MainClass using EasyMock it has the following snippet

```
MainClass mainclass = new MainClass();
OtherClass otherClass = EasyMock.createMock(OtherClass.class);
Callback callback = EasyMock.createMock(Callback.class);

otherClass.getOtherData("test", callback);

EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {

@Override
public Object answer() throws Throwable {
  callback.printData(message);
  return null;
  }
}).once();
```

Its giving following error :-

**Unexpected method call OtherClass.getOtherData("test", MainClass$1@7c03092a):
 OtherClass.getOtherData("test", EasyMock for interface Callback): expected: 1, actual: 0**

I am using a combination of EasyMock and PowerMock. Any help or pointers will be of great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by doing as below line in test case:-

```
otherClass.getOtherData(EasyMock.isA(String.class), EasyMock.isA(Callback.class));
```

Comment: You should not need isA. For "test" that is certain. For Callback, it shouldn't be the case either but I guess I don't have the full test here. The `replay` is missing and the recording of `printData`.